# axios.patch and data loading issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to react, just but my first MERN stack - a simple to-do style app.

While both my post and delete functions are working fine, and the getData() function is firing so my dom gets updated with the new list of 'notes', this is not the case for my update function.

While the note is updating successfully on the database, the dom doesn't reload with the new updated data, even though I have placed the getData function there...

I think the problem is that the patch request is lagging, so the getData function fires before the updated data is actually in the database...

Any solutions out there? I've only posted my main app.js file, and my routes.

What is the correct way to deal with this problem? I realise i could try a delay but that seems a bit hacky

The Function in question:

```
//UPDATE NOTE
async updateNote(_id, newNoteContent) {
  const updatedNote = {
    content: newNoteContent
  }
 await axios.patch('http://localhost:5000/'+ _id, updatedNote)
 .then(console.log('item ' + _id + ' has been updated'))
 .then(this.loadData())
}
```

#### APP.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Note from './components/note.js';
import Form from './components/form.js';
import EditBox from './components/editBox.js';


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    notes: [],
    dataLoaded: false,
    toggleEditBox: false,
    noteToEdit: null,
    noteToEditContent: null,
  }

//CDM which triggers first load
 componentDidMount() {
  this.loadData()
 }

//function for loading our data from the db when required
async loadData()  {
   await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/notes')
   .then(response => {
    const notes = response.data.reverse();
    console.log("fetched")
    this.setState({ notes: notes, dataLoaded: true, toggleEditBox: false })
  })
 }

//ADD NOTE to the database
async addNote(noteContent)  {
  const newNote = {
  content: noteContent
  }
 await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', newNote)
 .then(post => console.log('item ' + post.data._id + ' has been added'))
 this.loadData()
}

//DELETE NOTE from the database
async deleteNote(_id)  {
  await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/'+_id)
 .then(post => console.log('item ' + _id + ' has been deleted'))
 this.loadData()
}


//Function to open edit box
triggerEditBox(_id, content) {
  this.setState({ toggleEditBox: true, noteToEdit: _id, noteToEditContent: content})
}

//UPDATE NOTE
async updateNote(_id, newNoteContent) {
  const updatedNote = {
    content: newNoteContent
  }
 await axios.patch('http://localhost:5000/'+ _id, updatedNote)
 .then(console.log('item ' + _id + ' has been updated'))
 .then(this.loadData())

}



 render() {

  let notes;

  if (this.state.dataLoaded) {
    notes = 
     <div className="note-container">
       {this.state.notes.map(note => 
       <Note
        content={note.content}
        deleteNote={() => this.deleteNote(note._id)}
        triggerEditBox={() => this.triggerEditBox(note._id, note.content)}
     />)}
   </div>

  } else if (!this.state.dataLoaded) {
    notes = <h3>Loading</h3>
  }


//editbox
  let editBox;

  if (this.state.toggleEditBox) {
    editBox = 
    <EditBox 
    content={this.state.noteToEditContent}
    _id={this.state.noteToEdit}
    updateNote={(_id, newNoteContent) => this.updateNote(_id, newNoteContent)}/>
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">

      {editBox}

      <Form onSubmit={(noteContent) => this.addNote(noteContent)}/>

      {notes}

    </div>
   );
  }

}
export default App;
```

#### ROUTES

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    const Note = require('../../models/Note') // Pull in our Note model

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello, soon I will be a MERN stack app!')
    });

    // GET = RETRIEVE ALL NOTES

    router.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
        Note.find()
        .then(notes => res.json(notes));
    });

    // POST = ADD A NOTE TO THE DB
    // as the root of the route '/notes' is already defined in the server.js we dont need to have here

    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
      const newNote = new Note({
        content: req.body.content
      });
      newNote.save().then(note => res.json(note));
    });

    // DELETE = DELETE A NOTE FROM THE DB
    // we add the property param:id

    router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => { 
      Note.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
    });


    // UPDATE = UPDATE A NOTE IN THE DB
    router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
      Note.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(item => item.update({ content: req.body.content }));
    });


    // we cant use 'export default' in this particular file
    module.exports = router;
```

### Update 09/20/2019

its all working well. Thanks!!

Here are the updates I made:

```
// UPDATE = UPDATE A NOTE IN THE DB 
router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Note.findById(req.params.id)
  .then(item => item.update({ content: req.body.content }).then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
});
```

and

```
async updateNote(_id, newNoteContent) { 
  const updatedNote = { 
    content: newNoteContent 
  } 
  await axios.patch('http://localhost:5000/'+ _id, updatedNote) 
  .then(console.log('item ' + _id + ' has been updated')) 
  this.loadData() 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call `this.loadData()` the same as you do in the other function, as a separate call after the `axios....` call instead of setting it as a `.then` callback ?

Comment: Hey @itus! Have tried this as pasted below, however, then for some reason the getData function doesn't execute, and I can't figure out why that would be... As pasted below:

async updateNote(_id, newNoteContent) {
  const updatedNote = {
    content: newNoteContent
  }
 await axios.patch('http://localhost:5000/'+ _id, updatedNote)
.then(console.log('item ' + _id + ' has been updated'))
this.loadData()
}

Comment: You don't send a response from `router.patch` on your server.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! omg yes now its all working well. Thanks!! Here are the updates I made:

    `// UPDATE = UPDATE A NOTE IN THE DB
    router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
      Note.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(item => item.update({ content: req.body.content }).then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
});`


and

`async updateNote(_id, newNoteContent) {
  const updatedNote = {
    content: newNoteContent
  }
 await axios.patch('http://localhost:5000/'+ _id, updatedNote)
 .then(console.log('item ' + _id + ' has been updated'))
this.loadData()

}`